# Haskell SDL Binding: How to blit sprites with transparent color?

Tags: haskell, sdl

I want to blit a sprite to a surface using Haskell's SDL binding, but I don't know how to define the transparent color in the sprite's surface. Here is the code so far:

```
module Main where

import Graphics.UI.SDL as SDL
import Graphics.UI.SDL.Image as SDLi

main = do
    SDL.init [SDL.InitVideo]
    screen <- SDL.setVideoMode 500 500 32 []
    SDL.fillRect screen Nothing (SDL.Pixel 0x00FFFFFF) 

    ball <- SDLi.load "30ball.png"

    SDL.blitSurface ball Nothing screen Nothing

    SDL.flip screen

    delay 2000
    SDL.quit
```

In the Sdldotnet-Library, I could set the properties of *ball* with something like:

```
ball.Transparent<-true
ball.TransparentColor<-Color.FromArgb (0, 255, 0)
```

Any idea how I can achieve the same in Haskell's SDL binding?

[image: ... here is the sprite...]

Here is the working version after implementing Banthar's advice:

```
module Main where

import Graphics.UI.SDL as SDL
import Graphics.UI.SDL.Image as SDLi

main = do
    SDL.init [SDL.InitVideo]
    screen <- SDL.setVideoMode 500 500 32 []
    SDL.fillRect screen Nothing (SDL.Pixel 0x00FFFFFF) 

    ball <- SDLi.load "30ball.bmp"
    b2 <- convertSurface ball (surfaceGetPixelFormat screen) []

    t <- mapRGB (surfaceGetPixelFormat b2) 0 255 0 

    setColorKey b2 [SrcColorKey, RLEAccel] t 

    SDL.blitSurface b2 Nothing screen Nothing

    SDL.flip screen

    delay 2000
    SDL.quit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [setColorKey](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/SDL/0.6.2/doc/html/Graphics-UI-SDL-Video.html). You can find more info [here](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlsetcolorkey.html). If you are using PNGs the simplest way is to use alpha channel.

Comment: Thanks! It worked after adding setColorKey and converting the surface!